# Logical Operation to isolate word from field

Tags: architecture

I'm doing some studying regard the computer architecture. IN the logical Operations section, it asks this question:

Which operations can isolate a field in a word?

1. AND
2. A shift left followed by a shift right

I'm not sure how can those stated operation isolate a field in a word. I tried to search for example but I can't find any. Could anyone offer a deeper explanation and example for this? Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand the two concepts field and word in this question?

Comment: I do, word is a contiguous combination of fields (around 4 bytes each, depend on the specification of the computer). What I'm not sure is how these logical Operator can isolate field from a word?

Answer (score 6):

The answer is AND.
Lets say we have a two byte word a=x35B8. By performing an AND operation with x00F0, we get x00B0. In the result, B has been isolated from the initial word.
But the second option, A shift left followed by shift right cannot do that.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a 8 bit word, a = 01101011. You want to isolate a field consisting leftmost 4 bit, b = 0110.
By performing AND operation (01101011 & 11110000) you get 0110.
In the result b has been isolated from a.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful operation that isolates fields is AND.
You can find the answer in Page 88.

Comment: this should have been a comment

Comment: They gave the answer but not the explanation why. In my guess, I think that if we have a words fill with 0, only the the bits in the field we need to extract are 1, use and AND operator will get a new words with desired field (or some similar mechanism).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is AND, and the reasons are as follows.

1. The AND operation has the capability to MASK bits. For example, AND 0b1100 1111 can mask any bit number in the third and fourth leftmost bit. 0b1111 1111 AND 0b1100 1111 = ob1100 1111; the 1 represents the unchanged bit, and the 0 represent the bit you wanna change. So, you can use 0 to mask any bit you want to "clean" a bit field in any place. For example, 0b 111111 ...... 111111; you can clean the last three field of this number by AND 0b111111....111000.
2. However, the "A shift left followed by a shift right" can only CLEAN a bit field in the leftmost. If you wanna clean the middle of 0b111111111111, you cannot use "A shift left followed by a shift right", but you can use "AND 0b1111100000011111" to deal with it.